Blender bake texture is black
This previously worked fine, however now any time I bake, I just get a black texture and I have no clue why. I tried looking for answers but their proposed solution didn't do anything for me.
Here's the node setup:

It looks like this on my model:

Then, I select the object and select this image:

Here are the bake settings:

And the render settings as well:

After hitting 'bake', the image just turns black:

Thanks in advance.

Solution was to open the console (window > toggle system console) and look for errors.
In my case, I had errors where blender tried to open a file in a directory that didn't exist. Creating the directory manually solved the issue.
The error looked like this:
E0504 03:11:14.022554 27532 tile.cpp:464] Error opening tile file: Could not open "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\blender_a42480\cycles-tile-buffer-6356-1883955203000-12-0.exr" (No such file or directory)
Error writing tile to file

The solution is to open terminal or cmd and execute:
mkdir C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\blender_a42480\ and try baking again.
Or, just navigate to the folder through explorer or whatever.
